# template specialization function c++

Tags: c++, templates, cout

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< typename T >
T silnia( T w ) {
    cout << "not special" << endl;
}
template<>
int silnia<int>( int x ) {
    cout << "special" << endl;
}

int main() {

cout << silnia<double>(5) << endl;
cout << silnia<int>(5) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
not special
nan
special
4712544
```

Can someone help me understand where there two additional lines came from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely getting a compiler warning (at least) telling you that your template returns a `T` and `int` respectively, yet you provide no return values, which is **undefined behavior**. You should return the type that the function claims it is going to.

```
template< typename T >
T silnia( T w ) {
    cout << "not special" << endl;
    return w;
}

template<>
int silnia<int>( int x ) {
    cout << "special" << endl;
    return x
}
```

Why does it matter? Because you are using `std::cout` to try to output the returned values of these function calls.

```
cout << silnia<double>(5) << endl;
cout << silnia<int>(5) << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Both function templates have a return type, but the implementations don't return anything. You have *undefined behaviour* because you're attempting to use the return values. This has nothing to do with templates.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template< typename T >
T silnia( T w ) {
    cout << "not special" << endl;
    return w;
}
template<>
int silnia<int>( int x ) {
    cout << "special" << endl;
    return x;
}

int main() {
  cout << silnia<double>(5) << endl;
  cout << silnia<int>(5) << endl;
}
```

Output

```
not special
5
special
5
```